# Shell command get all files between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, shell

I have a directory with files like this:

```
/home/fichier/2017-10-01_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-02_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-03_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-05_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-06_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-07_Opens.tsv
```

I'm using PHP like this to get all dates, where `$range` is an array of dates:

```
for($k=0;$k<sizeof($range);$k++)
{ 
 $path = '/home/fichier/'.$kk[$j]."_Opens".tsv";    
}
```

The result when dates bewteen 2017-10-03 and 2017-10-06 are chosen is:

```
/home/fichier/2017-10-03_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-05_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-06_Opens.tsv
```

The loop is taking a very long time when I have big date range (for example, more than 6 months).
Is there any solution to get all files with one command and save these in an array without using a loop?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "fichier" i don't know whats you goal but read the directory and use the files.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but you might be looking for a function like [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), which will return all files in a directory matching a given pattern.

Comment: @Stony :  i mean i have a file and in the file i have like this : 
2017-10-01_Opens.tsv 
2017-10-02_Opens.tsv
...

Comment: @iainn : ok i well see thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit use shell_exec this you file:

```
/home/fichier/2017-10-01_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-02_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-03_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-05_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-06_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-07_Opens.tsv
```

use like this :

```
 $files = shell_exec("ls -d /home/fichier/*0[3-6]_Opens.tsv");
```

Output:

```
/home/fichier/2017-10-03_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-05_Opens.tsv
/home/fichier/2017-10-06_Opens.tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Here is [demo](https://eval.in/889422)

```
<?php

$range = array(
'/home/fichier/2017-10-01_Opens.tsv',
'/home/fichier/2017-10-02_Opens.tsv',
'/home/fichier/2017-10-03_Opens.tsv',
'/home/fichier/2017-10-05_Opens.tsv',
'/home/fichier/2017-10-06_Opens.tsv',
'/home/fichier/2017-10-07_Opens.tsv',
);

/*
   you may use explode() also like below
   $last = explode('/',$val);
   $date = explode('_',$last[count($last)-1]);
   $date = strtotime( $date[0] );
   return  $date >= strtotime('2017-10-03') && $date <=  strtotime('2017-10-06');   
*/

$result = array_filter($range, function ($val){
    preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/", $val, $match);
    $date = strtotime($match[0]);
    return  $date >= strtotime('2017-10-03') && $date <=  strtotime('2017-10-06');  
});

print_r($result);

// to reset keys use : print_r(array_values($result))

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => /home/fichier/2017-10-03_Opens.tsv
    [3] => /home/fichier/2017-10-05_Opens.tsv
    [4] => /home/fichier/2017-10-06_Opens.tsv
)
```

Comment: thank you for your response
but i need to get with one command shell
like this :
$path = '/home/fichier/2017-10-30_Opens".tsv";    
this commande is give you all fichier like this